# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/xml/bind/DatatypeConverter

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

Estoy haciendo una aplicación en equipo, somos 4 y todos usan Windows menos yo ([mac](/questions/tagged/mac)). Esta aplicación usa una base de datos con `MySQL`.
Al principio tenia `JDK 10`, ahora tengo el `1.8 (8)`. Tengo dos versiones de [netbeans](/questions/tagged/netbeans), la [netbeans-8.2](/questions/tagged/netbeans-8.2) para `Developers` y la [netbeans-9](/questions/tagged/netbeans-9) Apache. No me funciona con ninguna de las dos y con ningún `JDK`, el error que me da es el siguiente:

```
>    Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/xml/bind/DatatypeConverter
>       at implementacion.Login.hash(Login.java:58)
>       at implementacion.Login.comprobacion(Login.java:34)
>       at interfaz.InterfazConsola.login(InterfazConsola.java:33)
>       at interfaz.InterfazConsola.run(InterfazConsola.java:23)
>       at xcapeapp.App.main(App.java:31)
>    Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter
>       at >java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:582)
>       at >java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:190)
>       at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:499)
>       ... 5 more
```

La base de datos funciona bien, tanto al resto del equipo en la aplicación como a mi por consola, ademas la he manejado también con `MySQL WorkBench` y todo correcto. El fallo me salta al hacer **Login**, creo que ni si quiera accede correctamente a la DB.
Cabe destacar que usamos [git](/questions/tagged/git) para estar siempre actualizados y para las versiones y que la aplicación tiene una interfaz gráfica programada con [java-swing](/questions/tagged/java-swing) (aunque no se llega a ejecutar ya que la llamada a esta en el main esta comentada).

Answer (score 1):

Esa librería que te marca es parte de [jaxb](/questions/tagged/jaxb), a partir de [java-9](/questions/tagged/java-9) ya no forma parte del SDK por ser una librería usada mayormente en componentes empresariales.

Si tu código lo compilas usando Java 9 o 10 puedes usar el truco

```
--add-modules java.se.ee
```

Si planeas una solucióna  largo plazo que funcione en cualquier versión de Java lo más recomendable es unsar un sistema de construcción coomo por ejemplo [maven](/questions/tagged/maven), en el que le agregarías en el archivo `pom.xml` las dependencias que se quitaron del JDK algo así:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jaxb</groupId>
    <artifactId>jaxb-runtime</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.2</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>jakarta.xml.bind</groupId>
    <artifactId>jakarta.xml.bind-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.2</version>
</dependency>
```