# anotation @WebService y @WebMethod Spring boot 4

Tags: java, spring, java-8, jax-ws

Buen día,
Como primera vez tratando de consumir un WebService me he estado documentando con la libreria [JAX-WS](https://www.baeldung.com/jax-ws)

pero al momento de realizar la parte de la interfaz de servicio me he encontrado con que no encuentra los import de `javax.jws.WebService` y `javax.jws.Webmethod`.

He intentado buscando por eclipseMarketPlace y tambien por medios de instalación externos de librerias pero no he logrado entender porque me marca error al realizar el import.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

he buscado, pero no he podido encontrar una solución o una libreria altera.
llegue a pensar que tal vez estaba deprecated, pero incluso todos los ejemplos que he visto las tienen como necesarias.

Comment: que versión de Java tienes?

Comment: La version de Java es 8. JDK 1.8 con JRE 1.8

Comment: En versiones posteriores debes agregar JAXB a mano, posiblemente sea otra cosa. Lamento no haberte podido ayudar :(

Comment: de hecho eso me es muy de ayuda. como podría instalar JAXB en Eclipse?

Comment: no es posible instalarlo en eclipse. Pero en tu proyecto si es maven yo lo agrego así: https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/355584/342

Answer (score 0):

Buen día,
Agradezco mucho a los que comentaron y me ayudaron a buscar solución, el problema radico en el proceso de instalación del IDE Eclipse, lo pobre en un equipo que ya se encontraba con un proyecto diferente y funciono de manera correcta.
Faltaron algunos archivos y librerias que no se habían descargado para el Uso de WebService, Se realizo la instalación manual desde el menu

1.) help
2.) Instal new Software
3.) Buscar librerias WSDL e instalar