# Me sale este error en consola al tratar de registrar información en la base de datos

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot, eclipse, hibernate

```
public class GuardarClientePrueba {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            
            SessionFactory miFactory = new Configuration().configure("hibernate.cfg.xml").addAnnotatedClass(Clientes.class).buildSessionFactory();
                
            Session session = miFactory.openSession();
            
            try {
                
                Clientes cliente = new Clientes("Juan", "Perez", "Colonia 1");
                session.beginTransaction();
                session.save(cliente);
                session.getTransaction().commit();
                System.out.println("Cliente guardado con éxito");
                session.close();
            } catch (HibernateException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                miFactory.close();
            }
                            
        }
                        

}
```

Este error me sale en consola:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/xml/bind/JAXBException

    at org.hibernate.boot.spi.XmlMappingBinderAccess.<init>(XmlMappingBinderAccess.java:43)
    at org.hibernate.boot.MetadataSources.<init>(MetadataSources.java:87)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.<init>(Configuration.java:123)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.<init>(Configuration.java:118)
    at es.pildoras.conexionHibernate.GuardarClientePrueba.main(GuardarClientePrueba.java:16)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.xml.bind.JAXBException

    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:583)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
    ... 5 more
```

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [A que se debe el error de tipo NoClassDefFoundError?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/536514/a-que-se-debe-el-error-de-tipo-noclassdeffounderror)

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/xml/bind/DatatypeConverter](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/213333/exception-in-thread-main-java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-javax-xml-bind-dataty)

Comment: Me temo que no, creo que org.hibernate.SessionFactory esta obsoleto.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Debe incluir esta librerìa:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
    <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.1</version>
</dependency>
```